# User Profile Service failure: No more threads can be created in the system

Tags: multithreading, service, profile

Has anyone encountered this issue: We have windows boxes running on Citrix XenCenter and periodically they will stop allowing RDP connections to the host (error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TEFg.jpg )

"The User Profile Service service failed the logon. No more threads can be created in the system."

Currently the only way to resolve the issue is to reboot the vm. Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know of a fix or of a way to get into the host again without having to reboot? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no exact reason why this is happening in windows but this issue may occur if The C:Users(user-name) user profile folder was manually deleted instead of properly deleting the user account through User Accounts in the Control Panel. A user profile that is manually deleted does not remove the security identifier (SID) from the profile list in the registry. Since the SID is still present, Windows 7 will still try to load the profile by using the ProfileImagePath that points to a nonexistent path. Therefore, the profile cannot be loaded or The C:Users(user-name) user profile folder itself was manually renamed, instead of using the proper method in this tutorial or A unknown issue with the user profile entering into a backup state occurred or Corrupted user profile or Occasionally, Windows 7 might not read your user profile correctly, for example, if your antivirus software is scanning your computer while you try to log on. Try restarting your computer and logging on.

For permanent solution it may help you
http://www.solveinweb.com/solved-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-user-profile-cannot-be-loaded/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.